How to run droidcam on Ubuntu 20.04 when GLIBC_2.29 and GLIBC_2.28 aren't available
I am getting
droidcam: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by droidcam)
droidcam: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by droidcam)

when I tried to start droidcam on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.
The error messages indicate that the version of the GNU C Library on my system is too old for the version of DroidCam I am trying to run. To resolve this, I can either:

Update my operating system to a newer version that includes a more recent version of glibc. But I don't want to change my OS just for one app.
Or I can install a newer glibc which I read is very risky and complex as the OS depends on the gnuc libraries.

Is there any other alternative to this?

Use the newer version of Ubuntu.

The way the app is designed, you cannot run it with such an old version of glibc.
Updating glibc without upgrading ubuntu version will most definitely break your system. Support for Ubuntu 20.04 is ending in one year. If you want to use this app then continue upgrading to 24.04.
